# Access a grid control from method clicked of a button in a form

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

How to Access a grid control from method clicked of a button in a form AX 2009?

I have set the `AutoDeclaration` of the grid to Yes.

Then i have tried typing `this`. (Here i do not see the grid)

Also I have typed: `element`. (Here also i have do not see the grid)

I have saved & compiled the form.

I have put a breakpoint keyword in the clicked method at the end of the method
and noticed in the Variables window Grid variable is there but nothing appears
under it as its values or child objects.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have typed "Grid" and followed by a dot. I guess this is how we need to do it. Just wanted to update this thread.

Comment: Have you looked inside other forms with `AutoDeclaration` set? They are counted in hundreds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the grid is named `grid`, you have set the `AutoDeclaration` to Yes, then just reference it by the name.

Ex:

```
grid.setfocus();
```

You cannot make a dot-notation reference. Same thing with form variables declared in the `classDeclaration`.